# Select configurable column names in Oracle SQL

Tags: sql, oracle

I have a table with configurable column names which I can query like this:

```
SELECT
    column_name
FROM
    my_config
WHERE
    condition = 'MY_CONFIG_COLUMNS'
```

This is how 'my_config' tables looks like.

```
COLUMN_NAME              CONDITION
----------------------------------
    COLUMN1      MY_CONFIG_COLUMNS
    COLUMN2      MY_CONFIG_COLUMNS
    COLUMN3  NOT_MY_CONFIG_COLUMNS
    COLUMN4  NOT_MY_CONFIG_COLUMNS
```

My other table would look like this:

```
ID  COLUMN1 COLUMN2 COLUMN3 COLUMN4
ID1       X                       X
ID2       X       X       X       X
ID3       X               X
```

However, I would be looking to select only those columns that the query above returns in my other table, kind of like the below:

```
SELECT
    the_columns_in_the config
FROM
    my_other_table;
```

How could I achieve this?

Expected result:

```
COLUMN1 COLUMN2
---------------
      X 
      X       X
      X
```

Comment: Can you please add your expected result as well?

Comment: @BarbarosÖzhan that's the question amended with the expected result.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will need a dynamic query for the list of columns. It can be something like this:

```
DECLARE 
  l_column_list VARCHAR2(200);
  l_query       VARCHAR2(300);
BEGIN
  SELECT listagg(column_name,',') WITHIN GROUP (ORDER BY column_name)
    INTO l_column_list
    FROM my_config
   WHERE condition = 'MY_CONFIG_COLUMNS';
   
  l_query := 'SELECT '||l_column_list||' FROM my_other_table';
  EXECUTE IMMEDIATE l_query;
  --do whatever you ant with the results
END;
/
```

Comment: Thanks, I was trying to avoid writing dynamic code, but I see it is there is no other way around.

Comment: Unfortunately there is no dynamic column selection, you need to explicitly specify them, same goes for PIVOT. If you want to get the result with a single statement and have results as results from a query instead of DBMS_OUTPUT.put_line, you need to do it in dynamic SQL.

Answer (score 0):

That would be a join between these two tables (at least, that's how I understood the question; it would help if you posted sample data and desired result).

```
select a.column_name
from my_config a join my_other_table b on b.the_column_in_the_config = a.column_name
where a.condition = 'MY_CONFIG_COLUMNS';
```

Comment: Hi. I cannot join on b.the_column_in_the_config, since it would be the values which contain the actual column names.

Comment: I have just added some sample data for clarity.